# In WebStorm don't work Pug's argument "--pretty"

Tags: phpstorm, pug, webstorm

In WebStorm don't work Pug's argument "--pretty"

[image]

HTML file looks like:

[image]

But I want:

[image]

Please advise what to do?
I do not want to write on the command line

`pug --watch --pretty ./pug/ --out ./html/`

I want to make the default setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me when using the following setup:

```
Arguments: $FileName$ --pretty --out $ProjectFileDir$/html
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/html/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.html
```

[image]

[image]

the file in your screenshot doesn't seem to be produced by a file watcher - it's location doesn't match the output directory in your file watcher settings

Comment: Thank you so much!